# Ruby on Rails login & logout issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm newbie on ruby on rails application, from last few days I'm suffering about `Login` & `Logout` issue, now I have reached a solution, but now created a new issue. When I give invalid password then it showing

> Invalid email/password combination

when I give valid password then it showing `Logged In`.

But not working on after login logic.

This is my sessions_controller:

```
def new
end

def create
  user = Jobseeker.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    redirect_to home_path
    flash[:notice] = 'Logged In'
  else
    # Create an error message.
    flash[:notice] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
    render 'new'
  end
end

def destroy
  log_out
  redirect_to home_path
end
```

This is my model:

```
before_save { email.downcase! }

validates :first_name, :presence => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
validates :last_name, :presence => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, format: { with: /\A[^@\s]+@([^@.\s]+\.)+[^@.\s]+\z/ }

has_secure_password
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
```

This is my View:

```
<%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>
  <%= f.password_field :password%>

  <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
<% end %>
```

This is my sessions_helper:

```
# Logs in the given user.
 def log_in(user)
   session[:user_id] = user.id
 end

# Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
 def current_user
   @current_user ||= Jobseeker.find_by(jobseeker_id: session[:user_id])
 end

 # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
def logged_in?
  !current_user.nil?
end

# Logs out the current user.
def log_out
  session.delete(:user_id)
  @current_user = nil
end
```

This is my application_controller:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
include SessionsHelper
```

This is my layout:

```
<% if logged_in? %>
  <%= link_to "Profile", current_user.first_name %>
  <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: :delete %>
<% else %>
  <li><%= link_to "Login", login_path %></li>
<% end %>
```

How can I fix this issue?

I'm using `ruby 1.9.7` `Rails 4.2.5` & `mysql2`

That would help me a lot, please.

Comment: But where did you use this method to login? There is no `login` usage in controller, right? When you create a session you don't use your method from helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your create method, you are not setting the session variable which will mark the "Logged In" state of the user when he moves across the pages.

your `"current_user"` in session_helper.rb uses `session[:user_id]`, which should be `user_id` of the current user, set by you after login.

so, you should set `session[:user_id] = user.id` on your `create` method at `session_controller.rb`.

your modified session_controller#create should look like,

```
def create
  user = Jobseeker.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    login(user)
    flash[:notice] = 'Logged In'
    redirect_to home_path
  else
    # Create an error message.
    flash[:notice] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Hope this will fix your issue.

Edit:
Modifying session key names to match your context.

Comment: i have modified the code, a little. Hope this works now!